# Adapting a Vape box to run off a 12V car battery

Tags: amperage

[image]

Hello, I'm trying to adapt a vape mod so I can plug it in directly to my car cigarette lighter instead of using batteries. The device I'm using has a DNA 200 chip in it and according to the datasheet max input voltage is 12V and max amps is 23. According to a google search a car batter puts out around 48 amps. From my understanding the device will only draw as many amps as it needs or am I wrong? Could I connect the leads of my cigarette lighter adapter straight to the board or is there anything special I should do? Here is the full data sheet for reference.

Also I know it has a charge port on it. Problem is it charges to slow and I'm tired of messing around with batteries on long road trips.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that it will only draw as much current as it needs.

However, the cigarette lighter plug has a 10A fuse on every car I've been in so you won't be able to draw 23A from it without it blowing.

Also keep in mind that the 12V from a running car is not regulated and can be anywhere between 11-14V (even dipping down to 8V when cranking) with possible nasty spikes from the alternator. If you plug it in directly, you may damage the onboard electronics.

Comment: Wow I didn't think of the 10amp fuse. But lets just say I ran new outlet in the vehicle with the proper size wire and bigger fuse. Would installing a capacitor help keep the voltage steady?

Comment: The automotive electrics are pretty horrible to deal with. You'll need to read more into getting clean input power but you're also dealing with quite a significant amount of power (~275W) so I'd say to just forget it.